# How to Insert a List of Data into Pandas Multi-Index Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, data-science

How can I insert this list of data into a pandas DataFrame

```
orgdata = ['somestring', data[2], data[3], data[4], data[8], data[9], data[10], data[14], data[15], data[16], data[20], data[21], data[22], data[26], data[27], data[28], data[32], data[33], data[34], data[38], data[39], data[40], data[44], data[45], data[46] ]
```

where 'data' is another list of data out of which i parse specific data.

I have a list of columns names which is also derived from the 'data' list

```
colnames = ['USN', data[0], data[6], data[12], data[18], data[24], data[30], data[36], data[42]]
```

Now I need to have three subcolumns under each column, so i do this

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([colnames, ['IA', 'EX', 'Total']])
```

But when i try to insert this list of 'data' into a DataFrame like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(orgdata, columns=cols)
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 27
```

Also i get this error

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 25), indices imply (27, 25)
```

What am I doing wrong? The documentation provided online doesn't give much insight to this topic.

Are there any other ways to work around this? Any help provided is Appreciated.

Edit:

First I make a list of 'data' from the response of a request I made to. Here's an instance of the data i received from the response.

```
data = ['15EC41', 'LIC', '40', '60', 'P']
```

This is the sort of data i'm working  with.

Comment: Can you provide a **[mcve]**? By minimal, `data` need only have 3-5 values. Many of us want to be *sure* we are solving your precise problem, this is the only way we can be certain.

Comment: Sorry but the value you provide for `data` is incompatible with the text...

Comment: Apologies for not making the data list clear @Lorenz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap `orgdata` in brackets **and** ensure that it's length is equal to the number of columns that you have, like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([orgdata], columns=cols)
```

When you are creating your `MultiIndex`, you are passing `orgdata` as a list of 25 values (i.e. `Shape of passed values is (1, 25)`). You then define your list `colnames` (I'm assuming) as a list of strings, with length 9. Then you create your `MultiIndex` using `from_product()` with another list of 3 values, therefore giving you `indices imply (27, 25)`. The `25` here stems from the fact that you are passing `orgdata` to your dataframe constructor as a single list, so it will attempt to parse each individual value as it's own row. You need to wrap this in brackets to ensure that each value will be assigned to a column (since each list in the constructor is interpreted as a single row). Finally, you either need to ensure you have `25` columns to match your passed `orgdata`, or pass `27` values inside of `orgdata`.

Using your sample data, here is a minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['15EC41', 'LIC', '40', '60', 'P']

orgdata = ['somestring', data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]]

colnames = ['USN', data[2]]

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([colnames, ['IA', 'EX', 'Total']])

df = pd.DataFrame([orgdata], columns=cols)
```

Yields:

```
          USN                40          
           IA      EX Total  IA  EX Total
0  somestring  15EC41   LIC  40  60     P
```

A bit more complex example to set index:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = ['15EC41', 'LIC', '40', '60', 'P']
data2 = ['62F793', 'DUH', '52', '85', 'O']
data3 = ['9734HJ', 'IAS', '34', '94', 'D']

orgdata = [['somestring', i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4]] for i in [data1, data2, data3]]

colnames = [data1[0], data1[2]]

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([colnames, ['IA', 'EX', 'Total']])

df = pd.DataFrame(orgdata, columns=cols)

USN = [0, 1, 2]

df.index = USN; df.index.name = 'USN'
```

Yields:

```
         15EC41                40          
             IA      EX Total  IA  EX Total
USN                                        
0    somestring  15EC41   LIC  40  60     P
1    somestring  62F793   DUH  52  85     O
2    somestring  9734HJ   IAS  34  94     D
```

Comment: It works now, I got your point where I was passing incorrect number of arguments in 'orgdata' . I only wanted to have 3 subcolumns starting from the second column hence I passed 25 instead of 27 arguments. I solved the problem by removing 'somedata' from the list and removing the column name 'USN' . I now have to think of others way to append one column 'USN' to the DataFrame as an index.

Comment: You can set your index using `df.index = ________`

Comment: Yes it is. `df = df.set_index('USN')` assuming `'USN'` is a column in `df`. Feel free to upvote / accept my answer if this helped!

Comment: That's the problem, I can't have 'USN' as a column because if I do I'll need to have three subcolumns  under 'USN' ( which is undesired ). Is it possible to exclude a column while multi indexing to avoid this issue?

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah, just exclude 'USN' as a column then and see my edit above.

Comment: @rahlf23 : your example works but... I'm missing why `df.append([orgdata])` would not add a second row - currently it yields an error ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'

Comment: You can do the following: `df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([orgdata], columns=cols))`, however it's much more efficient to store all of the data in a list of lists and only convert to dataframe once all data has been assembled

Answer (score 0):

You call `DataFrame` with `orgdata` which is 25 items => `df` is expected to be 25 columns. The `columns` argument only specifies the labels for data. Therefore the mismatch, `columns` is in effect 27 items.

Can you make clear how would you like to 'insert' data (and not only labels)?

Minimal example I used:

```
import pandas as pd
data = range(50)
# 25 items
orgdata = ['somestring', data[2], data[3], data[4], data[8], data[9], data[10], data[14], data[15], data[16], data[20], data[21], data[22], data[26], data[27], data[28], data[32], data[33], data[34], data[38], data[39], data[40], data[44], data[45], data[46] ]
# 9 items
colnames = ['USN', data[0], data[6], data[12], data[18], data[24], data[30], data[36], data[42]]
#27 items
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([colnames, ['IA', 'EX', 'Total']])
#giving error
df = pd.DataFrame(orgdata, columns=cols)
```

Comment: Wouldn't df.Dataframe(orgdata, columns= cols ) automatically insert the data at the specified labels if the number of columns match?

Comment: Absolutely I think that @rahlf23 's answer proves that (but you need to wrap orgdata in []). I misunderstood your use of 'insert' by thinking you wanted to add additional data.

Comment: About that, how would I be able to insert data into the DataFrame without erasing the present contents to the next index? I require this because I'm making multiple requests to a web page and the data output differs each time and has to be inserted/ appended to the DataFrame.