# Pandas, Multi Column Table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, multi-index

Am trying to create a multi-column table, meaning a column has three sub-columns.

I tried a solution from this: [How to Insert a List of Data into Pandas Multi-Index Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042298/how-to-insert-a-list-of-data-into-pandas-multi-index-dataframe)

But the thing is that it passes a list, each item in the list corresponds to a column; i want to pass a data frame and align the values to each sub column.

```
med = pd.DataFrame({
      'Gold':[54, 37, 37, 14, 19, 19, 9, 10, 2],
      'Silver': [42, 40, 26, 16, 22, 14, 8, 9, 9],
      'Bronze': [41, 49, 29, 32, 33, 12, 9, 7, 11],
})

colnames = ['Masculine']

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([colnames, ['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze']])

df = pd.DataFrame([med], columns=cols)
```

What i need is that "Masculine" appears to the top of that "med" Dataframe and the values are aligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to generate a MultiIndex?

You can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat({'Masculine': med}, axis=1)

# OR
df = pd.concat([med], keys=colnames, axis=1)
```

output:

```
  Masculine              
       Gold Silver Bronze
0        54     42     41
1        37     40     49
2        37     26     29
3        14     16     32
4        19     22     33
5        19     14     12
6         9      8      9
7        10      9      7
8         2      9     11
```